# Error "de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.runtime.Mongod - Got some response, should be an error message"

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to test de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo version 4.9.3 and mongo-java-driver version 3.12.14.

Based on https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo/blob/main/docs/Howto.md I've created following code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.bson.Document;

import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;

import de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.distribution.Version;
import de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.transitions.Mongod;
import de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.transitions.RunningMongodProcess;
import de.flapdoodle.embed.process.io.ImmutableProcessOutput;
import de.flapdoodle.embed.process.io.ProcessOutput;
import de.flapdoodle.embed.process.io.StreamProcessor;
import de.flapdoodle.reverse.Transition;
import de.flapdoodle.reverse.TransitionWalker;
import de.flapdoodle.reverse.transitions.Start;

class NullStreamProcessor implements StreamProcessor {
    @Override
    public void process(String block) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProcessed() {
    }
}

public class TestMongoDBembed {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        StreamProcessor nullStreamProcessor = new NullStreamProcessor();

        Mongod mongod = new Mongod() {
            @Override
            public Transition<ProcessOutput> processOutput() {
                ImmutableProcessOutput nullProcessOutput = ProcessOutput.builder()
                        .output(nullStreamProcessor)
                        .error(nullStreamProcessor)
                        .commands(nullStreamProcessor)
                        .build();
                return Start.to(ProcessOutput.class)
                        .initializedWith(nullProcessOutput)
                        .withTransitionLabel("create null output");
            }
        };

        try (TransitionWalker.ReachedState<RunningMongodProcess> running = mongod.start(Version.Main.V7_0)) {
            try (MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(running.current().getServerAddress().toString())) {
                MongoDatabase db = mongo.getDatabase("testDatabase");
                MongoCollection<Document> col = db.getCollection("testCollection");
                col.insertOne(new Document("testString", "testString"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting following error:

```
22:16:13.941 [TestMongoDBembed.main()] ERROR de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.runtime.Mongod - Got some response, should be an error message
```

How to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try to set https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo/blob/0148baff2e043cbb77d5de352a0fa35087862372/src/main/java/de/flapdoodle/embed/mongo/commands/MongodArguments.java#L70 to true to avoid excessive mongod output..

In any case just open an issue on github:)